# Carrierwave/Minimagick not processing images after upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, carrierwave, minimagick

I am having trouble implementing a simple image uploader with Carrierwave/Minimagick gems in RoR.

I'm trying to convert the file to grayscale upon upload, but I am getting an error. Here is the code:

**image_uploader.rb:**

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Include the Sprockets helpers for Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  include Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper
  include Sprockets::Helpers::IsolatedHelper

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Process files as they are uploaded:
   process :convert_to_grayscale

  def convert_to_grayscale
    manipulate! do |img|
      img.quantize(256, Magick::GRAYColorspace)
      img = yield(img) if block_given?
      img
    end
  end
```

When I try to upload a file, I get the following error:

```
uninitialized constant ImageUploader::Magick

app/uploaders/image_uploader.rb:36:in `block in convert_to_grayscale'
app/uploaders/image_uploader.rb:35:in `convert_to_grayscale'
```

I believe this is due to the Magick::GRAYColorspace enum constant. Any ideas why this isnt working?

Answer (score 1):

Is the `manipulate` function that loads images to memory? Does It return a image list?

I think that the images aren't loaded correctly. The problem isn't the Magick enum.

Here is a sample example:

```
require 'RMagick'

clown = Magick::ImageList.new("clown.jpg")
clown = clown.quantize(256, Magick::GRAYColorspace)
clown.write('monochrome.jpg')
```

Comment: Here's what the carrierwave documentation says about manipulate!():

**manipulate!()**
Manipulate the image with RMagick. This method will load up an         image and then pass each of its frames to the supplied block. It will then save the image to disk.

Gotcha

This method assumes that the object responds to current_path. Any class that this module is mixed into must have a current_path method. CarrierWave::Uploader does, so you won’t need to worry about this in most cases.

Yields

MiniMagick::Image
manipulations to perform
Raises

CarrierWave::ProcessingError
if manipulation failed.